# Itertools writes some letters which are not in the list - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import time, itertools, win32com.client

print("Ctrl+C to start...")

while True:
    try:
        time.sleep(0.01)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("BruteForcing will start after 3 seconds...")
        time.sleep(3)
        break

shell = win32com.client.Dispatch('WScript.Shell')
msgs = 0

#here we go!
chrs = '0123456789'
min_length, max_length = 6, 6
file = open('data.di', 'a')

for n in range(min_length, max_length+1):
    for xs in itertools.product(chrs, repeat=n):
        x = ''.join(xs)
        for m in range(0, len(x)):
                shell.SendKeys(x[m])

        shell.SendKeys("{ENTER}")
```

well, this programe gonna make a random number (Lenth = 6 digits) `x` and write them in a box and then press enter (As a bot). it works in the 1st fine but for some reasons, it starts giving random symboles and numbers later.

Example:

```
13&&
001
2121521
7-011
à'&é-é2
```

I would like to know if there are any bugs in the script and why this is happening. Thanks

Comment: `itertools.product()` doesn't do anything randomly, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html

Answer (score 0):

Use [`random.choice(seq)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html?highlight=random.choice#random.choice):

```
import random
for n in range(min_length, max_length+1):
    for _ in range(n):
        shell.SendKeys(random.choice(chrs))
    shell.SendKeys("{ENTER}")
```

Sends 6 random digits followed by enter.

Comment: i used itertools b/c i'll need whole the possible numbers using 6 digits not just a random number